# css position trouble

Tags: css

I have a div and an image inside it as a background:

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="background.png" class="stretch" alt="" />
    <div class="header">
    <span>header</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="picture">
    <img src="pic" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 0;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #3A4549;
    margin-bottom: 
}
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7vk/

How can I add the image right under the header without specifying an absolute position?
Right now it goes under the background image. Thanks!

Comment: can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? you can use an image from [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com) or [placekitten](http://placekitten.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/3j7vk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're not just adding the image as a background to the div?

```
 #background {
    background: url(background.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /*other rules*/
  }
```

If the image is just a background, it shouldn't appear in the markup at all.

See this page on the [background-size property](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFYQFjAD&url=http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/&ei=Z_d6T4CaGoPagAfL7eSLAw&usg=AFQjCNF_IKE1itPYdA-V7J_2lzwzwu9HqA).

Comment: I can't do that because I need to stretch the image vertically

Comment: that's what the background-size property does.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that you're not using CSS's background-image property, but to answer your question, you can give elements z-index to specify their order and make them appear on top of each other. It only works when the position property is specified, but rather than making it absolute, make it relative:

```
.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Then give your .header a z-index of it's own:

```
z-index: 2;
```

But to be honest, using CSS's background properties would be the better option in my opinion.

Comment: .container 
{
    background: url(box_bg.png)  repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: cover;
} I have this now but it doesn't show the image at all

Comment: Is the path to your image correct? According to your comment, the image should be in the same folder as the CSS.

Comment: Yes it it in the same folder. The issue is I have a png image that I need to repeat on X, but I also have to stretch it vertically

Comment: In the following, change {image-width} for the actual image width: background-size: {image-width}, 100%; - that will stretch the height of the background image to 100% and allow you to tile the image across the x-axis with it's original width.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to use an `img` as your background you can do it like so:

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/600/" class="stretch" alt="" />
    <div id="container">
        <div class="header">
            <span>header</span>
        </div>    
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#background, .stretch, #container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
.header {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #3A4549;
    margin-bottom: 
}
.pic 
{
    height: 114px;
}​
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/SrvyD/

That way everything in your container flows like a plain html document and you don't have to position everything.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was looking for, I would have voted this answer also but I don't have enough reputation. Thank you also!